# load test kubernetes proxy and improve scalability

Tags: performance, testing, proxy, load, kubernetes

What are the possibilities and options to load test the kubernetes proxy and record the performance. What are the tools that can be used and how can scalability be measured ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about kube-proxy specifially, but you can try out the [node-perf project](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/node-perf-dash).

There is also a great demo for scale testing services [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/scale-demo).

The networking e2e tests also have a specific [networking perf test](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/test/e2e/networking_perf.go) that you can run against a local or remote cluster.